# date range in postgresql for a given period

Tags: postgresql, date-range

I have the following records in a table, as image below. The last period is December / 2019.

[image: Table structure and data]

I would like to list the periods within a range of 2 years (backwards) from the current date.

For example: today 09/10/2019, list periods from 01/01/2017 to 12/12/2019

I have difficulty assembling the query below.

```
SELECT c_period_id, name, startdate, enddate 
FROM adempiere.C_Period 
WHERE startdate BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '2 year' AND now() 
order by startdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your problem is, but if it is rounding the dates to the year boundary, this might serve:

```
WHERE startdate >= date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '2 years'
  AND startdate <  date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 year'
```